# How to open .mkd database file?

Tags: pervasive

Please help me in opening files with .mkd extension. I have tried to install ftp server and sql server but I'm not able to open it. I have tried to convert it into csv file so that I can import to phpmyadmin. Please help me in getting this?

Comment: Write what KIND of file is this. *.mkd extension can be used by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

MKD file is a Pervasive SQL Database.You need a Pervasive SQL engine to open .mkd file.
[Pervasive SQL Database](http://www.pervasive.com/database)